# Why SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services keep crashing when connecting to remote database server instance?

Tags: windows-7, database, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Background**

I successfully setting up a database for SQL Server Reporting Services in Windows Server 2008 R2 using Reporting Services Configuration Manager with "Create a new report server database" option. The next step I want to do is test connecting the created database remotely via a client machine running Windows 7 SP1.

**Problem Statement**

I installed same version of SQL Server 2008 R2 into client machine & begin connecting to remote server instance. Using "Database" => "Change Database" => "Choose an existing report server database" shows this screen, all seems to be working fine until this point:

[image]

However whenever I trying to use "Test Connection" or advance to next step (expecting to select Report Server Database), it suddenly crashed with crash report given below:

```
Message:
  SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Configuration Manage has stopped working

Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: RSConfigTool.exe
  Application Version: 10.50.1600.1
  Application Timestamp: 4bb67784
  Fault Module Name: mscorwks.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.0.50727.5420
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4ca2b820
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00001a00
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID: 1057
```

A further look into Event Viewer => Windows Logs => Application shows this error log:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5420 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (70D6E92A) (80131506)
Faulting application name: RSConfigTool.exe, version: 10.50.1600.1, time stamp: 0x4bb67784
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.5420, time stamp: 0x4ca2b820
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00001a00
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

XML format of the error log:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-16T06:21:47.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>49529</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>ClientPC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>RSConfigTool.exe</Data> 
  <Data>10.50.1600.1</Data> 
  <Data>4bb67784</Data> 
  <Data>mscorwks.dll</Data> 
  <Data>2.0.50727.5420</Data> 
  <Data>4ca2b820</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>00001a00</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

How can I get rid of this error and connect to remote server instance properly?

Comment: Run Windows Updates on the machine and be sure all .NET (all security updates too for that matter) and then reboot once those are applied and check Windows Updates again just in case and apply others that may be there after a reboot and keep repeating until no others are left to update. Be sure that you apply all updates to SSMS on the client machine. Also, the SQL instance update version may matter and be the issue too if it needs updated. Just saying give this some thought and a try... You only need SSMS components on the client and not any SQL instances or services.

Comment: Make sure your .NET Frameworks are upgraded and/or matched as well.